# I need a part from a html textfield using java

Tags: java, html

I want to scan a barcode in an html textfield but only need a few characters from that barcode.. I've tried str.substring using the code below. But I want to replace 'helloworld' with the value from the textbox.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var id = "helloworld"; 
    var res = id.substring(1, 7);
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Should this be tagged "javascript" rather than "java"? Not clear why you're referring to a "barcode". Suggest some editing to give a bit more detail of what's in the textfield and what you'd like to extract.

Comment: thanx for you comment, I've changed it.. the barcode is on a paper form, this barcode is scanned with a barcode-scanner and this result comes in the textfield. now I want to extract the information in the textfield. for instance the barcode result is 12BABQ1223450. Now I need only the characters ABQ, without the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get a value from a text box?

HTML: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Barcode Example
    </title>
    <link href="script.js" rel="JavaScript" type="text/js" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="barcode" id="textbox" onkeyup="validateBarcode()" />
    <br />
    <span id="barcode_error" style="display: none; color: red;">
      Barcode must only have numbers
    </span>
    <br />
    <button id="submit_btn" onClick="myFunction()">
      Submit
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

If so, here's the code:

JavaScript: myscript.js

```
var barcode;
var textbox;

function myFunction() {
    barcode = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = "Barcode: " + barcode + "<br />";
    // ^ br is to make it have multiple barcodes listed
}

function validateBarcode() {
    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(textbox.value))) {
        document.getElementById('textbox').style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('barcode_error').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('submit_btn').diabled = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('textbox').style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementById('barcode-error').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('submit_btn').diabled = false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :-)